# Do Adeos and KVM only support Linux as guest?

Tags: linux, kvm, hypervisor, adeos

I'd like to run multiple operating systems (i.e., Linux + a RTOS) through an hypervisor on an ARM device.

Are the [Adeos](http://home.gna.org/adeos/) and [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) hypervisors designed to only support Linux as guest OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Adeos but on KVM yes you can run Linux/Unix/Windows and many other major operating systems. [Here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Guest_Support_Status) you can find the list of guest Operating Systems supported by KVM.

I will recommend you to use KVM as it is more stable and being used in production environments.

Comment: Another question: how long is the boot time with KVM ? Do I have to boot a whole Linux kernel with KVM module to have the hypervisor working ? In that case, the boot would be very long...

Comment: What do you mean by boot time? boot time of guest OS or boot time of host OS? But yes ! You will need an x86 machine running a recent Linux kernel on an Intel processor with VT (virtualization technology) extensions, or an AMD processor with SVM extensions (also called AMD-V).